# Can't find the right ID Selection or Xpath for Google Search Input Box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking for Google input box selection, where I can't find the right ID selection; by using Selenium, I want to send keys or search terms to the Google Input box. Please, I like the perfect id selection or Xpath Selection.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
 
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id('input')
search_bar.send_keys("I want to be a Genius")
search_bar.submit()
#sleep(5)
 
#end
driver.close()
```

Here is the screenshot of the Present Google Source code for input Search Terms
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_bar.send_keys("I want to be a Genius")
search_bar.submit()
```

It worked for me. Using chrome to inspect search box element there is an attribute called `name` with value of `q`

[image]

Comment: It works for me too, thanks for your response, but I don't find the "q", on Google Search,  Inspect Element Selection, If you please to share your thoughts.